# Is it possible to create a table that can be edited by the user in python. i.e. Username and Password box

Tags: python

So i am doing a school project rn and making a simple program that grants access to people who know the username and password. I am pretty bad a coding and know that you can do this sort of thing on html forms or whatever but is it possible to make a box that can contain variable that can be edited within the box.

IF this makes no sense to make it as simple as i want to make a log in interface on python. Is that a thing?

Comment: Yes, it's quite easy. You could do a very simple way, like taking input that checks a list and sees if the expected values match the input. Or you could make it better by using a database to store the names and password in separate columns. You can then ask the user for input, and query the database for the name and check if the associated password value matches. This is all quite easy with Python, and there are a lot of tutorials to read on this. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! And I will need luck cause I am a bit of a coding spastic.